# tsc includes other files automatically

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I've got a problem with tsc that's driving me insane
I've got a file `b.ts` in `src` folder. and a `a.ts` in my project root folder.
this is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build3"
  },
  "rootDir": "src"
}
```

but when i compile it using `tsc -build tsconfig.json` i get both a and b file in build folder, including folder src. but I want just `b.js` in build folder!. if I remove `a.ts` thing will be alright. but is there's any .ts file in root folder then everything gets compiled!
I've tried using `files`, `exclude`, `include`, `rootDir` options in config file but nothing works...

HELP ME!!

Comment: Are you sure your tsconfig is properly read and use by typescript?

Comment: Tell us about your environment, are you using VS?

Comment: `"rootDir"` isn't a top level a property. It's a compiler option!

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks man! u saved my life 

Answer (score 2):

As Aluan Haddad mentioned. `rootDir` should be under `compilerOptions` and combined with a `"include":["src/*.ts"]` solved my problem.

Thanks.